# Loop through Controls and check a value

Tags: vb.net

Among others I have few NumericUpDown controls in my form and I would like to check if value of this controls is entered in range between 1 and 50.

Like this:

```
    ''general check
    Dim errors As String = ""
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is NumericUpDown Then
            '' error here
            If ctrl.value < 1 Or ctrl.Value > 50 Then
                errors += ctrl.Name + " is out of range." + Environment.NewLine
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

With this code "ctrl.value" is underlined blue and I get error: 'value' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

How to get this working?

Comment: Set the Minimum and Maximum allowed value. Problem solved. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.maximum(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: In that case control will automatically repair user inputs (to minimum or maximum) what is not wanted in this application.

Comment: Then do it properly, handle the validating and validated events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to cast `ctrl` to type `NumericUpDown` since `Control` does not have a `.Value` property. You can do this using `TryCast`. It tries to cast control into correct type and if it fails it returns `Nothing`.

```
    Dim errors As String = ""
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        Dim num = TryCast(ctrl, NumericUpDown)
        If num IsNot Nothing AndAlso (num.Value < 1 OrElse num.Value > 50) Then
             errors += ctrl.Name + " is out of range." + Environment.NewLine
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you Magnus. Your solution work as expected. Anyway, it is silly since i determined that control IS typeof NumericUpDown under IF statement...

Comment: Yes you have determined that control is of type `NumericUpDown` but that does not redefine the variable. It is still of type `Control`.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `ctrl` as `Control` and only **asked** if it is a `NumericUpDown`. You haven't **cast** it to one.

My preferred way of doing this is with LINQ.

```
Dim errors = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, _
    Me.Controls _
        .OfType(Of NumericUpDown)() _
        .Where(Function (x) x.Value < 1 OrElse x.Value > 50) _
        .Select(Function (x) ctrl.Name + " is out of range."))
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont say but this project is targeting to framework 2.0 where I haven't linq.

Comment: @user973238 - That must be rather annoying!

Comment: @Enigmativity The Cast to NumericUpDown is unnecessary here since `OfType` does both filtering and casting.

Comment: @Magnus - Thanks. I should have spotted that myself.